# Как отловить момент закрытия диалогового окна выбора даты DatePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android

Есть DatePickerDialog для установки даты.
Использую так:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == DIALOG_DATE) {
        DatePickerDialog tpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, dmy.Y, dmy.M - 1, dmy.D);
        return tpd;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Есть слушатель:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myCallBack = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dmy.set_dmy(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year);
    }
};
```

Как отловить момент закрытия диалогового окна выбора даты? Т.е. когда пользователь нажал кнопку Done на диалоговом окне, чтобы с полученными данными работать дальше в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
tpd.setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Отмена", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which == BUTTON_NEGATIVE) dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

Comment: Это не подходит, т.к. это дает просто еще одну кнопку, Cancel, а основную, которая нужна, так и оставляет, а нажимать будут именно на нее.